# how to load test async python requests in celery using jmeter?

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, jmeter, celery

I have an API, which performs the task likes this:

1. Client sends the request.
2. The task is received by the celery worker and put in the message queue.
3. The response is sent as soon as the request is received and the task is executed.

Now, I am load testing my application on JMeter. In my server logs, whenever I send a request to the server, the response is received asap and the task is executed. But, JMeter is executing the whole query and sending me the response after the entire query is executed. Now, I want JMeter to send me the response as soon as the request is received, not when the whole query is executed.I want to record the response times of the server, when mulitple queries are sent.

How can I achieve this? Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks